# c - How to sort ascend array data in my code?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

Hello im new in C Programming. I wonder how do i sort data array on my code? Im having difficulties to explain the detail, so I just give the running program example. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    struct Barang
    {
        int Kode;
        int Jumlah;
        int HargaSatuan;
        float Total;
        char Nama[20];
    }Brg[10];

    int i,j,harga=0,banyak;
    float rata;
    printf("Berapa banyak barang? : ");
    scanf("%d",&banyak);
    for (i=0;i<banyak;i++)
    {
        printf("\nBarang Ke-%d\n",i+1);
        printf("Masukkan Kode : ");
        scanf("%d",&Brg[i].Kode);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Masukkan Nama Barang  : ");
        fgets(Brg[i].Nama,20,stdin);
        strtok(Brg[i].Nama, "\n" );
        printf("Masukkan Harga Satuan : ");
        scanf("%d",&Brg[i].HargaSatuan);
        printf("Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : ");
        scanf("%d",&Brg[i].Jumlah);
        //harga+=Brg[i].HargaSatuan;
    }
    printf("\n==============================\n");
    printf("Daftar Barang:\n");
    for (i=0;i<banyak;i++)
    {
        printf("\nBarang Ke-%d\n",i+1);
        printf("Kode         :  %d\n",Brg[i].Kode);
        printf("Nama Barang  : %s\n",Brg[i].Nama);
        printf("Harga Satuan : %d\n",Brg[i].HargaSatuan);
        printf("Jumlah       : %d\n",Brg[i].Jumlah);
        Brg[i].Total+=(float)(Brg[i].HargaSatuan*Brg[i].Jumlah);
        rata=(float)Brg[i].Total/Brg[i].Jumlah;
        printf("Total Harga Semua Barang : %.2f\n",Brg[i].Total);
        printf("Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : %.2f\n",rata);
    }
    printf("==============================\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Here is the running program output:

```
Berapa banyak barang? : 3

Barang Ke-1
Masukkan Kode : 28
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Test A
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 2984
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 21

Barang Ke-2
Masukkan Kode : 12
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Test B
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 90
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 2

Barang Ke-3
Masukkan Kode : 2
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Test C
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 8901
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 2

==============================
Daftar Barang:

Barang Ke-1
Kode         :  28
Nama Barang  : Test A
Harga Satuan : 2984
Jumlah       : 21
Total Harga Semua Barang : 62664.00
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 2984.00

Barang Ke-2
Kode         :  12
Nama Barang  : Test B
Harga Satuan : 90
Jumlah       : 2
Total Harga Semua Barang : 180.00
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 90.00

Barang Ke-3
Kode         :  2
Nama Barang  : Test C
Harga Satuan : 8901
Jumlah       : 2
Total Harga Semua Barang : 17802.00
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 8901.00
==============================

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 37.663 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I wonder how to sort the data (ascend) by the 'Kode' number variable? I wanted to look like this:

```
Berapa banyak barang? : 3

Barang Ke-1
Masukkan Kode : 28
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Test A
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 2984
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 21

Barang Ke-2
Masukkan Kode : 12
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Test B
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 90
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 2

Barang Ke-3
Masukkan Kode : 2
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Test C
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 8901
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 2

==============================
Daftar Barang:

Barang Ke-1
Kode         :  2
Nama Barang  : Test C
Harga Satuan : 8901
Jumlah       : 2
Total Harga Semua Barang : 17802.00
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 8901.00

Barang Ke-2
Kode         :  12
Nama Barang  : Test B
Harga Satuan : 90
Jumlah       : 2
Total Harga Semua Barang : 180.00
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 90.00

Barang Ke-3
Kode         :  28
Nama Barang  : Test A
Harga Satuan : 2984
Jumlah       : 21
Total Harga Semua Barang : 62664.00
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 2984.00
==============================

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 37.663 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I have think about how to achieve this output for 1 hour, but i can't find the answer. How to get that i expected output? Thankyou.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking.  There are numerous sorting algorithms that could be implemented to sort your data, and there is the standard `qsort()` function, too. For a maximum of 10 elements, pretty much any sorting algorithm will do.  So what, specifically, do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use array of pointers to `struct Barang` to store the base address of each record.

```c
struct Barang* ABP = malloc (banyak * sizeof(struct Barang*));
for (int ri = 0; ri < banyak; ++ri) {
    ABP[ri] = Brg + ri;
}
```

2. Use standard library function `qsort()` to sort your records.

```c
qsort (ABP, banyak, sizeof(struct Barang*), cmp);
```

3. Define the callback compare function `int cmp (void*, void*);` We define it to sort records in `ascending` order of field `Kode`.

```c
int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
    return ((*(struct Barang**)p)->Kode > (*(struct Barang**)q)->Kode);
}
```

4. Use the array of sorted structure pointers to access your records.

```c
for (int ri = 0; ri < banyak; ++ri) {
    printf("Kode         :  %d\n", ABP[ri]->Kode);
}
```

Make a note of how we access the structure members, using `->` dereference operator.